# Multiple by record value

Tags: sql, sql-server

A have a SQL Server statement which calculates the total length of time of Schedules, amongst over totals. I want to include an if/case statement which will allow me to multiple the length of the schedule by 2 if another cell is empty else leave it as it is.

I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ScheduledDuration) AS TotalScheduleDuration, 
    SUM(FirstCarerDuration) AS TotalCareDuration, 
    COUNT(NumberOfRows) AS NumberOfRows, 
    SUM(NumberOfCarers) AS NumberOfCarers
FROM
    (SELECT
         @@ROWCOUNT AS NumberOfRows,
         CASE
             WHEN SecondCarerID = '' THEN 1
             ELSE 2
         END as NumberOfCarers,
         (DateDiff(MI, StartTime, EndTime)) * (NumberOfCarers) as ScheduledDuration, 
         DateDiff(MI, SignIn, SignOut) as FirstCarerDuration,
         DateDiff(MI, SecondSignIn, SecondSignOut) as SecondCarerDuration,
         (DateDiff(MI, SignIn, SignOut)) + isnull(DateDiff(MI, SecondSignIn, SecondSignOut),0) as CareDuration
     FROM 
         tblSchedules
     WHERE 
         SignIn != 'M' 
         AND SignOut != 'M' 
         AND ProviderID = 123 
         AND DateOfCare = '2016/01/09') DT
```

I am using a case to set the multiplier value as `NumberOfCarers` but I get the error message:

> Invalid Column Name NumberOfCarers

How can I multiple the `ScheduleDuration` by the result of the case statement?

Other then not multiplying the rest of the query works fine.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you either need to duplicate the expression or nest the query so you can refer to its column by the alias. Since you've already got a nesting I think the most immediate fix it to just do the multiplication in the summation.

```
SELECT
    SUM(ScheduledDuration * NumberOfCarers) AS TotalScheduleDuration,
    SUM(FirstCarerDuration) AS TotalCareDuration,
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRows, --COUNT(NumberOfRows) AS NumberOfRows,
    SUM(NumberOfCarers) AS NumberOfCarers
FROM
    (       
    SELECT
        --@@ROWCOUNT AS NumberOfRows,
        CASE WHEN SecondCarerID = '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as NumberOfCarers,
        DateDiff(MI, StartTime, EndTime) as ScheduledDuration, 
        DateDiff(MI, SignIn, SignOut) as FirstCarerDuration,
        DateDiff(MI, SecondSignIn, SecondSignOut) as SecondCarerDuration,
        DateDiff(MI, SignIn, SignOut) 
            + isnull(DateDiff(MI, SecondSignIn, SecondSignOut), 0) as CareDuration
    FROM tblSchedules
    WHERE
            SignIn != 'M' AND SignOut != 'M'
        AND ProviderID = 123 AND DateOfCare = '2016/01/09'
    ) DT
```

By the way `@@rowcount` is going to be the result from the previously executed query. I think you just want `count(*)` anyway rather than `count(NumberOfRows)`

Comment: Wouldn't this multiple the TotalScheduleDuration by either 1 or 2, rather then the individual ScheduleDurations? Not all schedules will have the same NumberOfCarers

Comment: @Josh Nope. And which of 1 and 2 would it use if it tried to do it that way?

Comment: I've had chance to test this and what you said works perfectly thank you